# Map and filter an observable stream RXJS

Tags: rxjs, observable, flatmap

I have an observable from a firebase collection which contains objects as the stream.

I want to filter these objects and then map them to add 2 further attributes, however I cannot get it working.

```
 this.firestoreService.colWithIds$('stuff',
  ref => ref.orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
    .limit(20))
  .pipe(
    map((outputArray: any[]) => {
      return skills.map(s => {
        if (s.user.uid !== this.user.uid && !this.bloomFilterService.test(s.uid)) {
          return { ...s, loaded: false, fadeOutState: 'out' };
        }
      });
    })
  )
```

This is nearly there however it still returns undefined for those i want to filter out.

I have tried filtering the observable, but then i can map - and as for FlatMap, I can't make sense of the documentation and how i can achieve what I'm trying to do with it

Answer (score 1):

That's because you don't filter, you simply return undefined. You should probably do:

`return skills
  .filter(u.user.uid !== this.user.uid && !this.bloomFilterService.test(s.uid))
  .map(s => ({ ...s, loaded: false, fadeOutState: 'out' });`